# Conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}(X | X^2 + Y^2)$, with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, expected-value

I have two independent random variables $X, Y$ with Poisson distribution say that $\mu$ and $\lambda$. I want to calculate the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\left(X | X^2 + Y^2\right)$.

It is known that $\mathbb{E}(X | X^2 + Y^2) = f(X^2 + Y^2)$ for a certain Borelian function $f$.

Can I tell something about $\mathbb{E}(X^2 | X^2 + Y^2)$ if i know $\mathbb{E}(X | X^2 + Y^2)$? Of course I know that $X^2 + Y^2 = \mathbb{E}(X^2 + Y^2 | X^2 + Y^2)$. Maybe this should helps.

Can I get some hints?

Comment: You probably need to determine the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X^2+Y^2$. You could do this by first getting the joint density and then dividing by the density of $X^2+Y^2$.

Comment: Are you sure you've written the question down correctly? I ask because this feels like it's secretly a number theory question, since $X$ and $Y$ must be integer-valued and you're conditioning on the sum of their squares.